# Pointer Variable vs Global variables in Stack operation in C

Tags: c, pointers, stack, global-variables, dynamic-allocation

This is a simple program to do a Stack operation by linked lists this is the formal way .I understand the concept of pointers needed to indicate the top of stack and the pointer to point to the next node.But is it necessary to make pointer variables of the Structure Variable in this case struct student variable i.e typedef to Student .I declared as Student *(any name);.and then dynamically allocate memory through malloc.I could instead use a global variable as Student (anyname);and use is to fill information then push to stack.So what is the difference and advantages and disadvantages to use global variables or pointers.

And about the program i myself wrote it and it is working fine.

```
typedef struct student{
    int roll;
    char name[30];
    struct student *next;

}Student;

typedef struct stack{
Student *top;

}Stack;

Student *makestudent(int r,char n[]){
Student *newstudent;
if((newstudent=(Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student)))==NULL){
    printf("Out Of Memory");
 }
 else{
newstudent->roll=r;
strcpy(newstudent->name,n);
newstudent->next=NULL;
}

return newstudent;

 }


void push(int r,char n[],Stack *s){
Student *student=makestudent(r,n);
student->next=s->top;
s->top=student;
}

Student *pop(Stack *s){

Student *st=s->top;
s->top=s->top->next;
return st;

}
```

Comment: reentrancy, which implies thread-safety.

Comment: *"I could instead use a global variable as Student (anyname);and use is to fill information then push to stack."* But you would need to `push()` a **copy** of the `struct` to your stack, which would still require you to allocate memory for it. Alternatively, you could use a static array of `struct student` with a fixed size, and then your `push()` and `pop()` functions would work with a stack index instead of a linked list. BTW there is an error in `pop()` - it does not `free()` the memory allocated in `push()`.

Comment: It would obviously require a memory to allocate but in compile time.The pointer variable allocates memory in runtime.
And also the program can be done without using the dynamic memory allocation which i think makes it much more easier than dealing with pointers.i.e
Using  a global Structure Variable;

Comment: Please digest my earlier remark. Having entered data into a static `struct` so you can "stack" it, the next record will over-write the static `struct`. So you still need to allocate memory at runtime, and copy the `struct` to it - unless as I said, your stack is a static array instead of a linked list, in which case you can enter data directly into the next array element, and increment the array pointer.

Comment: So the program I've written is the only way to operate on linked stack?

Comment: The point of linked lists is they use dynamically allocated memory. Otherwise you could use static array, but it will either not have enough elements, or waste memory by having too many elements.

Comment: Can you show what you mean? How would you write the code without using pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code using a static array LIFO stack, without using pointers. The major problem is you have to guess how big this stack will be. If you want to reallocate when it grows too big, you are back to using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXS    10          // stack size

typedef struct {
    int roll;
    char name[30];
} student;    

student studs [MAXS];
int stacktop = 0;

int push(student *s) {
    if (stacktop >= MAXS)
        return 1;           //mega fail
    studs [stacktop++] = *s;
    return 0;
}

int pop(student *s) {
    if (stacktop <= 0)
        return 1;           //mega fail
    *s = studs [--stacktop];
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    student entryput = {42, "Arthur Dent"};
    student entryget;
    if (push (&entryput))
        return 1;           // need to handle better than this

    if (pop (&entryget))
        return 1;           // need to handle better than this
    printf ("Name: %s, Roll: %d\n", entryget.name, entryget.roll);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Name: Arthur Dent, Roll: 42
```

Comment: @immibis it was not your question, but here is an answer to not using memory pointers. It is not satisfactory, because pointers are simply unavoidable in C, and is one reason for that language's power.